# Assembly declaration in Xamarin's custom renderers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was reading through the [Xamarin Forms documentation for custom renderers](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) trying to make sense of what the assembly attribute required for each implementation of a renderer actually did. I took a look at the [C# documentation for Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wxf689z(v=vs.110).aspx) and couldn't seem to find a (simple) explanation. Going with the MyEntry example outlined in the documentation, could someone shed some light as to what is happening with this assembly attribute/what it actually does?

For sake of clarity, these are the type of declarations I am talking about:

`[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyEntry), typeof (MyEntryRenderer))]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyEntry), typeof (MyEntryRenderer))]
```

`MyEntry` is the name of the placeholder class in your common (PCL or Shared) Forms library.

`MyEntryRenderer` is the name of the actual platform specific implementation class in your iOS/Android/WP project.

Essentially, you are telling Forms, "when you need to render `MyEntry` on Platform X, use the class `MyEntryRenderer`."

Comment: where is the Platform `X` defined?

Comment: @Felix Platform X is whatever project you're inside of. You'd put this renderer and the `assembly` attribute in the iOS/Android/Windows projects and customize each one individually for that platform